# How do I collapse an orgChart with all nodes when first displayed and then show first level of its children by select event?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, treenode, orgchart

I create an orgChart by pulling data from  json data.
at first ı want only show first level of orgChart. ı mean top of chart.
and then when ı click the node ı want to list children of clicked node. ı mean showing first degree relative children of clicked nodes.

here is my select event code when ı clicked

```
    function selectHandler(e) {
      //console.log(selectedItem);   
      /////////////////////////////////////
      var selection = chart.getSelection();
    var row;
    if (selection.length == 0) {
        row = previous;
    }
    else {
        row = selection[0].row;
        previous = row;
    }
    var collapsed = chart.getCollapsedNodes();
    var collapse = (collapsed.indexOf(row) -== 1);
    chart.collapse(row, collapse);
    chart.setSelection([{row: row, column: null}]);}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the collapse method during the ready event to collapse the nodes.
make sure to use `addOneTimeListener` when assigning the ready event.
otherwise, the nodes will be collapsed on every select.
this is because the ready event is fired when a node is collapsed / un-collapsed.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['orgchart']
}).then(function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
  data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');
  data.addRows([
    [{'v':'Mike', 'f':'Mike<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>'},
     '', 'The President'],
    [{'v':'Jim', 'f':'Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vice President</div>'},
     'Mike', 'VP'],
    ['Alice', 'Mike', ''],
    ['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'],
    ['Carol', 'Bob', '']
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // loop rows in reverse order
    for (var i = data.getNumberOfRows() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      // determine if node has children
      if (chart.getChildrenIndexes(i).length > 0) {
        // collapse row
        chart.collapse(i, true);
      }
    }
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    // get selection
    var selection = chart.getSelection();

    // determine if selection made
    if (selection.length > 0) {
      // collapse / un-collapse row
      chart.collapse(selection[0].row, (chart.getCollapsedNodes().indexOf(selection[0].row) === -1));
    }
  });

  chart.draw(data, {allowHtml: true, allowCollapse: true});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

note: there is issue with using the select event. the event is fired when a node is un-selected, and there is no way of knowing which node was un-selected.
as such, if the same node is clicked twice, nothing will happen on the second clicked.

it might make sense to use the default action,
of allowing the user to double-click the nodes to collapse / un-collapse.
and remove the select event all together.